# MVC5 Viewmodel loses strong type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have added MVC5 to an old Webforms project using NuGet. When I now try to call a view from MVC which is strongly typed like so:

```
@model MyNameSpace.MyModel
```

There is no error, but when I try to do anything (`@Model.SomeProperty`) with that model in the view, I get the following exception at runtime:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for "SomeProperty"

**UPDATE**

I changed

```
@model MyNameSpace.MyModel
```

to the old syntax

```
@inherits WebViewPage<MyNameSpace.MyModel>
```

and everything works, which is weird because obviously the WebViewPage is declared as the standard inheritance for all views in the web.config.

This is the Web.Config for the Views-Folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApp.WebClient" />

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried adding the namespaces to the root web.config:

```
  <pages enableSessionState="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
  </pages>
```

but nothing changed.

These are my assemblyBindings:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have not properly implemented the MVC upgrade. The first thing I can think of is that you do not have a web.config in your views folder or you do not have the proper sections defined in your web.config that allow the `.cshtml` pages to render/process correctly.

Comment: pasted the web.config from the Views-Folder. It looks good to me but who knows, I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: I think it looks pretty good too.  Did you make the proper changes to your root web.config file as well?

Comment: Only added assemblybindings there..

Comment: Could you check that  'namespaces' AND 'assemblyBinding' have been added to the root web.config

Comment: I do not have anything relating to 'namespace' in the root config. Assemblybindings are set up and are working (nothing worked without these).

Comment: When faced with a scenario like this, I find it helpful to create a MVC project from the VS template, ensure it runs, and then compare the differences (in configuration and project files) between the new project and your current one. This makes finding the missing pieces easier to spot.

Comment: `<appSettings><add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>` was my last hope but it also did nothing. I cannot spot any more differences in the config. The project file is huge, I think it will take a week to skim it...

Comment: Found a workaround with @inherits, but not the reason or solution to the problem.